# Transparent PNG material without dark

Tags: materials, node-editor, image

how do I make PNG transparent without dark?

I'm trying to add aurora borealis to this planet but it looks more dark than usual, I tried to put a multiply node for the clouds and it did worked but not for the aurora because it needs to be green and multiply node make it look white. I also tried different blend mode but it's not working, thanks for any help. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing controlling the factor of your mix shader. You need to use the alpha channel of your PNG file to control how the mix factor, so that the transparent parts are not mixed in.